# How can I give two alias to a table created from a query with MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
year
----------
1995
2000
2010
```

*(first three lines)

I would like to create a "diff" column which use the year entry:

```
 ind | year | diff
-----------------
  1  | 1995 | 0
  2  | 2000 | 5
  3  | 2010 | 10
```

In order to do so i have tried to create and ind column and modify the suggested here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-tips/mysql-compare-calculate-difference-successive-rows/)

though I'm not successful with giving the a second alias to the table i have created:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
      g1.ind
     (g2.year - g1.year) AS diff
FROM (
        select * from
                        (SELECT 
                            (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS ind, year 
                        FROM
                            movies) t

) g1 
INNER JOIN
g1 g2 ON g2.ind = g1.ind + 1
```

The error is:
Error Code: 1146. Table 'db_name.g1' doesn't exist

Comment: Ids are always contiguous?

Comment: I have re-edited my question - actually no, therefore I created a contiguous id column however now i have problem with giving the alias to the table i had created

Comment: So you would like to create a diff column, and an ind column?

Comment: yes, otherwise i don't have any idea how to create the diff column.

Comment: So it only exists in order to assist with the creation of a column you don't no how to create. Cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(year INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT my_table VALUES
(1995),(2000),(2010);
```

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.year
     , x.year - COALESCE(MAX(y.year),x.year) diff 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.year < x.year 
 GROUP 
    BY x.year;
+------+------+
| year | diff |
+------+------+
| 1995 |    0 |
| 2000 |    5 |
| 2010 |   10 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

...or...

```
SELECT year
     , COALESCE(year-@prev,0) diff
     , @prev:=year 
  FROM my_table
     , ( SELECT @prev:=null ) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY year;
+------+------+-------------+
| year | diff | @prev:=year |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1995 |    0 |        1995 |
| 2000 |    5 |        2000 |
| 2010 |   10 |        2010 |
+------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've over-complicated things a little.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    m1.id, 
    m1.year,
    IFNULL(m1.year - m2.year, 0) AS diff
FROM
    movies m1
LEFT JOIN
    movies m2 ON m2.id +1  = m1.id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Which outputs (using your data)

```
|id|year|diff|
+--+----+----+
|1 |1995| 0  |
|2 |2000| 5  |
|3 |2010| 10 |
```

If `id` doesn't exist, and doesn't need to be generated, we just wrap `m2.year` in the diff field with a `max`:

```
SELECT
    m1.year,
    IFNULL((m1.year - max(m2.year)),0) AS diff
FROM  movies m1
LEFT JOIN 
    movies m2 on m1.year > m2.year
GROUP BY m1.year
```

...then join on the years.  This gives:

```
|year|diff|
+----+----+
|1995| 0  |
|2000| 5  |
|2010| 10 |
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question to better explain the problem i'm dealing with. Can you suggest a solution for a case that instead of movie table i need to use a table which is a result of selection query? i have trouble with giving the alias in this case